# Forcing Format for Date textbox using appended javascript not working in FireFox

Tags: javascript, .net, firefox

The text box that I'm trying to force the formatting works in IE 8-11 and Chrome but not Firefox. The issue is that in Firefox you cant change the value in the text box at all. It's just stuck only way to change the value is the calendar next to the box. Here are the methods I'm using with related fields:

```
     public static void RegisterMask(System.Web.UI.Page Caller)
     {
        System.Text.StringBuilder strMask = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        strMask.Append("<script language=\"javascript\">");
        strMask.Append("function maskKeyPress(objEvent) {");
        strMask.Append(" var iKeyCode = objEvent.keyCode;  ");
        strMask.Append("if(iKeyCode>=48 && iKeyCode<=57){return true;}");
        strMask.Append("else{");
        strMask.Append("return false;}}");
        strMask.Append("</script>");
        strMask.Append("<script language=\"javascript\">");
        strMask.Append(" function mask(str,textbox,loc,delim,event){");
        strMask.Append("if (maskKeyPress(event)== false){return false;}");
        strMask.Append("var locs = loc.split(',');");
        strMask.Append("for (var i = 0; i <= locs.length; i++){");
        strMask.Append("for (var k = 0; k <= str.length; k++){");
        strMask.Append(" if (k == locs[i]){");
        strMask.Append(" if (str.substring(k, k+1) != delim){");
        strMask.Append("   str = str.substring(0,k) + delim + str.substring(k,str.length)}}}}textbox.value=str}");
        strMask.Append("</script>");
        System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Caller, Caller.GetType(), "Mask", strMask.ToString(), false);
     }
 protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    RegisterMask(this.Page);

    if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
    { 
        pMask(this.Page, ref txtStart, "/", "2,5");
        pMask(this.Page, ref txtEnd, "/", "2,5");
    }
 }
            <cs:Row runat="server" ID="rwStartDate">
                <LabelTemplate><asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbltxtStart"      AssociatedControlID="txtStart">Start</asp:Label></LabelTemplate>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtStart" Width="100" EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvStartDate" ControlToValidate="txtStart" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date" SetFocusOnError="true" CssClass="validator">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    <asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="csvStart" ControlToValidate="txtStart" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date" SetFocusOnError="true" CssClass="validator" ClientValidationFunction="Validator.validateDate" />
                    <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="#" runat="server" ID="lnkCalStart" ToolTip="Toggle Calendar" CssClass="calendar" />
                    <ajax:CalendarExtender runat="server" ID="ajxStart" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="calendarExtenderHelper" Animated="false" PopupPosition="Right" Format="M/d/yyyy" TargetControlID="txtStart" PopupButtonID="lnkCalStart" BehaviorID="ajxCalStart" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </cs:Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the onkeypress not being supported by firefox and needed to be change to onkeyup. Also had an issue with numpad which needed another set of keycodes.